# Wildfly Swarm debugging and Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I'm using Hibernate to utilize UUID generation for primary keys like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String id;
```

It's working when I separately build and run the package with

```
mvn clean package wildfly-swarm:package && jar -jar ...
```

Debugging the app fails though. When running the application like this:

```
mvn wildfly-swarm:run -Dswarm.debug.port=5005
```

Program compiles and debugging session starts normally, but fails later during startup with the following error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war#myPU\""],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}

Based on the some googling and reading StackOverflow, the problem is, that hibernate-core introduced in the dependencies clashes with the baked in classes. Swarm uses Hibernate as JPA provider. Based on some suggestions I have added hibernate-core dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

It doesn't help though. What would be correct way to use Hibernate annotations in the WildFly Swarm? WildFly Swarm version is 2017.10.0.

Comment: There can be classloading issues when using "mvn wildfly-swarm:run" because we don't start with an empty classloader.

You're best option is to use the agent to debug when using "java -jar"

Comment: Yeah, debugging with java -jar works ok :) (I managed to mess with the ordering of the cli args, but after I got it sorted out debugger works as expected)